# How to connect FTP server through AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ftp, aws-glue, private-subnet

I have wrote python shell script in AWS GLUE using paramiko client to connect to FTP server, but connection is failing as FTP server owner has not given access to the VPC.

Now I need to add a subnet for Glue , so that I can provide that subnet IP to the FTP owner so he can provide access to the GLUE service, but I am not able to find out how to map or add that subnet to glue or create a subnet for Glue

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do the following to get an Elastic IP for the Glue and then whitelist in your FTP service.

1. [Add a development endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-dev-endpoint.html)
2. Choose proper VPC, Subnet and Security Group while creating an endpoint.

   [image]
3. Create an Elastic IP, and attach to the Glue Endpoint. Refer [Access a development endpoint by attaching an Elastic IP address](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint-elastic-ip.html)
4. Use this Elastic IP for whitelisting in FTP service.